# Django startserver not recognizing built in python libraries?

Tags: django, python-3.x, server

I am running Python 3.7 and Django 2.1 I am using Django for the first time. I have set up a virtual environment to run my project. I have imported django into the virtual environment using pip, but when I try to issue the command

```
python manage.py runserver
```

I get the following error code

```
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function check_errors.<locals>.wrapper at 0x00000203257A1B70>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Environments\django_env\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 225, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Environments\django_env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 109, in inner_run
    autoreload.raise_last_exception()
  File "C:\Environments\django_env\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 248, in raise_last_exception
    raise _exception[1]
  File "C:\Environments\django_env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 337, in execute
    autoreload.check_errors(django.setup)()
  File "C:\Environments\django_env\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 225, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Environments\django_env\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "C:\Environments\django_env\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 112, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
  File "C:\Environments\django_env\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 198, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "C:\Environments\django_env\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Environments\django_env\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\models.py", line 2, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager
  File "C:\Environments\django_env\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\base_user.py", line 47, in <module>
    class AbstractBaseUser(models.Model):
  File "C:\Environments\django_env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 101, in __new__
    new_class.add_to_class('_meta', Options(meta, app_label))
  File "C:\Environments\django_env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 304, in add_to_class
    value.contribute_to_class(cls, name)
  File "C:\Environments\django_env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\options.py", line 203, in contribute_to_class
    self.db_table = truncate_name(self.db_table, connection.ops.max_name_length())
  File "C:\Environments\django_env\lib\site-packages\django\db\__init__.py", line 33, in __getattr__
    return getattr(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS], item)
  File "C:\Environments\django_env\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 202, in __getitem__
    backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE'])
  File "C:\Environments\django_env\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 110, in load_backend
    return import_module('%s.base' % backend_name)
  File "C:\Environments\django_env\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "C:\Environments\django_env\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 10, in <module>
    from sqlite3 import dbapi2 as Database
  File "c:\users\aguec\anaconda3\Lib\sqlite3\__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    from sqlite3.dbapi2 import *
  File "c:\users\aguec\anaconda3\Lib\sqlite3\dbapi2.py", line 27, in <module>
    from _sqlite3 import *
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

I have spent many hours searching for the problem online already but can't find a solution to my problem. I have opened python to check if sqlite3 is installed and it is. I have tried to use pip install sqlite3 in the virtual environment but that doesn't work.

I thought that when you create a virtual environment, Python already includes the libraries sqlite3 and _sqlite3?

Please any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple versions of python installed - virtualenv and anaconda which is causing conflicts. You will have to activate environ before running or directly use anaconda based environ as it has sqlite installed. Install sqlite package in your own virtualenv if that is what you intend to you using pip install.

Although not related to your package but below link will be useful in resolving the issue

https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/9263